# Etymology/Origin of "Грузия"

Tags: этимология, ономастика, toponyms

In many languages, the name of the country Georgia is derived from the name of St.George. In Georgian, Georgia is called  საქართველო(Sakartvelo), so obviously Грузия has nothing to do with it either. What is the origin of Грузия? Does it have anything to with the word груз maybe?

Comment: Why you don't just google it? Are we going to copy Wikipedia here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Самоназвание грузинского народа — картвелы, а страны, иначе известной
>   как Грузия, — Сакартвело этимологически объясняется следующим образом:
>   В I тыс. до н. э. западная часть Грузии по имени народа колхи
>   называлась Колхида. Собирательное название древнегрузинских
>   картвельских племён восходит к наименованию восточно-грузинского
>   племени картов и совпадает с самоназванием народа — картвелы. На
>   Востоке этот же народ называли гурз, гурдж, из этого названия в России
>   образовался этноним «гурзин», что позднее в результате перестановки
>   звуков превратилось в «грузин».

[Source](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD#.D0.93)

There is another [resource](http://speakrus.ru/articles/gruziny.htm) that mentions the original source of the information which in its turn says that the roots are yet unknown:

> "Краткий топонимический словарь" Hиконова: ...на востоке этот народ
>   называли /гурз/, /гурдж/ (этимология неизвестна), из этого в России
>   образовалось /гурзин/, в рус. языке с перестановкой звуков ("История
>   Грузии", т.I, Тбилиси, 1946, с.60).

Another interesting [resource](http://lenta.ru/articles/2010/05/21/gruzia/) says:

> Как пояснил Ленте.Ру составитель грузинско-английского
>   словаря, профессор Лондонского университета Доналд Рэйфилд, "Георгия"
>   происходит от восточного (персидского и тюркского) названия грузин
>   "гурдж" (которое, в свою очередь, восходит к некоему армянскому
>   корню). Оно сохранилось, например, в турецком названии Грузии
>   "Гюрджистан". Во времена Крестовых походов европейцы, услышав слово
>   "гурдж" от арабов, сблизили его по созвучию с именем Святого Георгия
>   (оно и впрямь происходит от греческого "землепашца"), который, как они
>   знали, особо почитается на Кавказе. Так и родилась (в XI-XII веках)
>   "Георгия".

Yet [another one](http://shkolazhizni.ru/archive/0/n-28452/)

> Русские на Кавказ пришли не через горные перевалы, а вдоль Каспийского
>   моря. Долгая война России с Персией за Дербент и Каспий очень живо (я
>   бы даже сказал, смешно) описана Ю.Тыняновым в романе «Смерть
>   Вазир-мухтара» в небольшой главе, начинающейся словами «В самом деле,
>   что же такое Кавказ?» Именно тогда, пожалуй, русские узнали о
>   существовании христианского царства «Гурджистан», где живут
>   «гурджины». Довольно скоро в русском языке «гурджины» превратились в
>   «грузинов», а страна, которую они населяют, соответственно в «Грузию».

One more resource [claims](http://poiskslov.com/word/%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8/) there is a city in Georgia named "Гурджаани". Wiki [confirms](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8).

> ГУРДЖААНИ , город (с 1934) в Грузии, в долине р. Алазани.
>   Железнодорожный узел. 12,9 тыс. жителей (1991). Винодельческие,
>   консервные заводы, мясокомбинат. Филиал тбилисского завода
>   "Микродвигатель". Театр. Краеведческий музей, Дом-музей Н. Вачнадзе.
>   Близ Гурджаани - грязевой курорт Ахтала. К юго-западу от Гурджаани -
>   3-нефная церковь 8-9 вв.

Comment: An interesting fact: in Japanese, the word for Georgia is グルジア (guruzia), so apparently it was imported from Russian.

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot about it [here](http://www.artsakh.info/forum/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=731), but I'll try to sum up to the best of my understanding:

The toponym "Груз-" with regard to Georgia apparently entered Russian from Arabic a very long time ago. Arab travelers or cartographers apparently learned it from the way some local peoples referred to Georgia or to some specific place in that region. The local root is related to the totemic cult of the Wolf, which was widespread in the region and can be traced to modern day.

I can add that the first part (Arabic origins) seems to be correct, since the original Hebrew word for Georgia (back in the 12th century) stemmed from the same root, before it was replaced with the modern Gruziya because of Russian (and very recently with Georgia for political reasons).